# How can I Upload jpeg to my UniWebView scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uniwebview

I`m making a simple app with UniWebView plugin.
In my application, a person gets to a shared site,
in case of technical problems a person can contact the site support service.
My problem is that I don't understand how to make it possible to send screenshots to the support dialog.

I tried to use javascript code and expected to be able to load images, but it didn't work.

in `uniWebView.OnPageFinished` method I added:

> view.AddJavaScript("window.addEventListener('click', function(event)
> {if(event.path[0].type ==
> 'file'){event.path[0].attributes.accept.value = '* /*';}});");

But still getting an error when trying to upload a screenshot [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUn2L.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be very simple. It was worth just updating the UniWebView plugin to the latest version